# AWS Cloudfront Link does not serve through the web

Tags: url, amazon-s3

I am using AWS S3 and Cloudfront to store images and render images on a webpage. I have managed to generate a signed URL using Cloudfront to render S3 Objects.

The problem is, I tried attaching that signed URL within an a tag for href='' tagger. I was hoping that, when users clicked on the link, it would direct them to the image through the web. Instead, the file is downloaded when a user clicks on the link.

How photo key is generated

```
var photoKey = $ctrl.clientDetail["_id"] + '/' + fileName;
```

I created a subdirectory for each user, and store the file in the respective subdirectory.

My Upload Function in AngularJS

```
s3.upload({
                        Key: photoKey,
                        Body: file,
                        ACL: 'public-read',
                        Metadata: {
                            'id': $ctrl.clientDetail["_id"],
                            'phone': $ctrl.phone
                        }
                    }, function(err, data){
                        if (err) {
                            $scope.uploadedFail = true;
                            console.log(err)
                            genericServices.setErrorInfo($scope.configErrorAddDocAlert, addDoc_reason);
                        }
                        else {
                            $scope.uploadedSuccess = true;
                            genericServices.setSuccessInfo($scope.configSuccessAddDocAlert, addDoc_success);
                        }
                    }
                );
```

What I found interesting was that when I manually uploaded a file in a subdirectory in the AWS S3 console, the generated URL was able to serve the file through the web.

How do I make it, so that the Object within the bucket is not a downloadable file, but a link?

Comment: Set the correct `Content-Type` on the image when you upload it.  Note also that `ACL: 'public'` seems very wrong if you want the object to be accessed with a signed URL.  Why are you setting this?

Comment: You are right, i changed it to private for ACL thanks! The content-type is application/octet-stream

Answer (score 1):

For those who faced the same problem, here is the solution.

When uploading, specify the content-type.

S3 Upload Process modified

```
s3.upload({
                        Key: photoKey,
                        Body: file,
                        ContentType: file.type,
                        Metadata: {
                            'id': $ctrl.clientDetail["_id"],
                            'phone': $ctrl.phone
                        }
                    }, function(err, data){
                        if (err) {
                            $scope.uploadedFail = true;
                            console.log(err)
                            genericServices.setErrorInfo($scope.configErrorAddDocAlert, addDoc_reason);
                        }
                        else {
                            $scope.uploadedSuccess = true;
                            genericServices.setSuccessInfo($scope.configSuccessAddDocAlert, addDoc_success);
                        }
                    }
                );
```

Initially, the type was application/octet-stream, so it was only downloadable.

Thanks you @michael-sqlbot for the comment

Comment: Happy to be of assistance.  One more warning... Object metadata is not private.  The metadata you add to objects is returned to anyone authorized to download the object, and it looks like you might be putting some sensitive or personal information in the metadata.  You will want to consider using [S3 Object Tagging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-tagging.html) instead of object metadata.  Alternately, a Lambda@Edge trigger could be used to strip the metadata.